# How to Configure a testnet for my substrate chain?

Tags: rust, test-network

I would like to set up a testnet for my substrate chain.

I did not find much information around. Can you please help me with articles/tutorials?

Thank you!

Comment: Some more info would be needed on what are you expecting as a testnet so answers can be a bit more on point and provide actual help.
Are you trying to create a testnet for parachains ?
You just want a solochain that runs the same runtime than your chain but with faster block production or smaller waiting times ?

Some info on those lines

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the tutorials for working with Substrate-based blockchain nodes: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/

I also found this article which could maybe help you with deciding what kind of testnet you want to setup, plus the required steps involved: https://vimukthi.com/how-to-configure-a-new-testnet-for-substrate-chain-2cfdce951b9f

Comment: The article is outdated :/

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you want to do and what information is missing?

Comment: I would like to add MyNewTestnet as in this article is doing: https://vimukthi.com/how-to-configure-a-new-testnet-for-substrate-chain-2cfdce951b9f  but I need also an open source code so I can understand it better where should I make my changes.

Comment: Any youtube video?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what changes you need more information about? 
Also, perhaps your answers can be found in the tutorials. Especially the 'getting started' and the 'work with pallets' tutorial.